# Can't seem to get GTK to allow overlapping controls

Tags: gtk, glade

I'm creating an application (in C/C++) using GTK(+3) and glade.  I'm kind of new at it, but I've been able to fumble my way through most of it based on tutorial/samples I've been able to find.  But I'm stuck on something.

I want to have a 'control' in my application that is basically an image (that I've loaded from disk, into memory), with a box superimposed over The image (with perhaps reduced opacity).  The user needs to be able to move this box around the image, and change the shape of the box (with the mouse).

I've found lots of GTK samples to help me along the way -- but nothing that does anything like that.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: GtkOverlay may be what you want.

Comment: As your box is not a control (since you want to change it's shape), then I suppose you'd be best served with a GtkDrawingArea and directly drawing in it with [cairo](http://cairographics.org).